# KeePass database with keyfile won't open in Ubuntu

Tags: keepass

I have KeePass (`.kbdx`) database with key file (`.keyx`) that was created with KeePass2 on Windows. I'm able to open the database on Windows (KeePass2) or Mac (strongbox). However, on Ubuntu 20.04, which is a dual boot with the Windows machine and the databse is stored in a shared mount, I am unable to unlock.

In KeePassXC I get a an invalid credentials error which states that if this reoccurs the file may be corrupted; KeeWeb just refuses to open it. I can confirm the file is not corrupted as I can open after the error in Windows and am certain the password/keyfile are correct.

Also, I can open a different shared `.kdbx` with no `.keyx` in Ubuntu or Windows.

I believe the files should be cross-platform. Is there a reason a `.keyx` generated in Windows won't work in Ubuntu?

**Edit**
I'm using the UI so I don't have exact commands to show but here is the process:

1. Open KeepPassXC UI
2. Select .kbdx
3. Select .keyx
4. Enter password

It returns with this message [image]

Obviously this looks like user error, but the same database password/keyx combo works in Windows.

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question and show us (copy and paste) the exact commands and error messages.

Comment: There is the possibility that different line endings in Windows and Linux files may be the reason your keyfile isn't working. You could try saving the keyfile under a new name using a Linux text editor and try with that file.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for tip. I changed to linux line endings but still get the same error.

Comment: I recommend contacting the KeePassXC team directly. You can find them, and ask question, on https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc. I do also reccomend looking at:
- https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/2863
- https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/2834
- https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/6390

Comment: I have a similar issue and to make things weirder when I copy the single keyx file directly from windows to my linux box I end up with two files x.keyx and x.keyx:Zone.Identifier:$DATA. To combat this I sent tthe key file through email.

I am not sure why this happens but on both KeePassXC and KeePass2 it says:

Failed to load specific file!
The composite key is invalid!
make sure the composite key is correct and try again...

I am using the exact same key file from windows and it even works on my android, just not in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of KeePassXC in the ubuntu software center... I should have checked the versions because I tried the second one on the list which was actually the latest version and it worked no problem[image: The correct keepassxc]